# Processing data from Google App Engine on a Google Virtual Machine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

My website runs on Python on Google App Engine, and I've setup a Virtual Machine to use libraries that weren't supported by the default App Engine environment. Now I need to send data from my app to the VM and retrieve the response. Data in this case will be an email address and an email message.

Currently I am testing with a POST request through urllib2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: On other option is to access your appengine app data from your VM via remote api.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi

Comment: The process will be initiated from App Engine. Can I use the Remote API to access a function on my VM?

Comment: I think the method you posted is best for the setup you have. I would personally look into Managed VM's[1] as they allow you to run any library while still keeping the scalability of App Engine. [1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/

Comment: I am using a Managed VM. What diffefent approach would be better in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking with the described POST request using urllib2. We decided we might move this part of the project to a different provider so better to not use Google Cloud only methods.